# Ubuntu GNOME and high resolution screen: icons in QT apps are too small. How to solve?

Tags: gnome, icons, display-resolution, qt

my brother got a new laptop, a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th generation. It features a screen with a rather large resolution of 2560x1440 px.

Out of the box, GNOME scales well the size of the text and the icons, as you may see from this screenshot of LibreOffice:
[image]

Unfortunately QT apps seem not to behave the same, as seen in this screenshot of TexMaker:
[image]

As you may see the icons are too small and rather difficult to reach.

How can he uniform the look&feel of the QT apps to the one of the GTK apps?
Is there some compatibility package that he has to install? Or some configuration to make?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can play around with the QT_SCALE_FACTOR and QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR environment variables.

I had the problem of a tiny UI font in calibre on the Gnome desktop on a 4K 15.6 display. I experimented with `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5 QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0.8 calibre` in the terminal and it worked!

So, basically (if my guess is correct), QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR controls the overall scaling except the font, while QT_SCALE_FACTOR controls font scaling only.

I also added these two variables to the desktop file of calibre:

**before**:

```
Exec=calibre --detach %F
```

**after**:

```
Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5 QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0.8 calibre --detach %F
```

Also you may want to take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/SourcetrailBugTracker/issues/523).

Comment: $ ldd $(which $NAME) | grep qt -i
ldd: missing file arguments
Try `ldd --help' for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on which version of *qt* you are using, `qt4` or `qt5`. The following will tell you which version of *qt* you are using.

`ldd $(which $NAME) | grep qt -i`

For `qt5` you can use an environment variable `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`, for `qt4` you can change font sizes using `qtconfig-qt4`, but it would appear that icon sizes don't scale.  You might, however, be able to use a different icon set, or if you are very energetic scale up another icon set yourself.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI for more details and details for other toolkits.

Comment: Also `qmake --version` should show which one you have. I have 5.9.5 and have this issue on all apps that use Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Para 1:__  You have several choices.  The situation can be resolved temporarily using the Displays setting under Systems Settings, or using a terminal and making use of the xrandr utility.

Para 2:__ Enter xrandr by itself, and you see the possible YYYYxXXXX settings recorded in the video card's RAM.  Pick one and enter xrandr -s YYYYxXXXX (i.e. 1024x768) and hit Enter.  The monitor will blank out, then come back at the new settings.  If it does not blank out, you are already at that setting. (Note the RAM settings can be in error.  There may be other hidden settings that were not included either).

Para 3:__ xrandr is an extremely powerful utility.  This is only scratching thec surface of what it is capable of.

Para 4:__ Note some applications will automatically adjust to the new borders.  Meny don't, as they were written with one size screen in mind.  You can find ways to deal with this usually if a horizontal or vertical scrollbar does not automatically appear at the  bottom or right side of the screen.

Para 5:__ One way is to move change the displayed window from its maximum settings and manipulate the borders.  Another is to move the Window off the center position.

Para 6:__ Another way is to use any included zoom or magnify feature in the app.  Another is to use Select All, then Copy and Paste to put the contents elsewhere, like in LibreOffice Writer or gedit (leafpad, kate, jedit, cream are reasonable alternatives).

Para 7:__ Putting the Copy & Paste into one of the text editors strips off the formatting and drops the link references, including images.  LibreOffice Suite keeps most of the contents intact. The Copy and Paste also handles text too small or hard to read by dropping all font, sizing, and coloring details.

Para 8:__ The most helpful web browser I have found for performing these and other tasks is FlashPeak's Slimjet, which is multi-platform and free.  In some cases, you simply cannot get control of what is displayed well enough to work at a lower resolution.

Para 9:__ But if you can't get the image or web page to to a useful size, you have several outs.  You have gsettings (dconf-editor is the GUI equivalent) for making changes in terms of fonts, size, magnification, the mouse, and much more.

Para 10:__ The most effective search tool combination I have found for gsettings is this:
        gsettings list-recursively | grep [whatever]

Para 11:__ I just used "gsettings list-recursively | grep cursor" without the quotes in a terminal window, and got a list of settings which had "cursor" in the line.  [whatever] can be anything, and grep makes it easy to combine searches in one string using the "|" pipe option to chain the output of the commans on the left to as the input for the next command to the right.

Para 12:__ I found one to change, "org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme ''".
I want to use DMZ-White-Large, a custom cursor theme on these forums that eliminate all other cursor size possibilities.  T make this change, I enter:

```
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme 'DMZ-White-Large'
```

Para 13:__ There is also a DMZ-White-Medium that sizes the cursor to 32 pixels.  Other sizes are 24 and 18, which is very very small on Hi-Res monitors at their maximum settinbgs (the default).

Para 14:__ There are at least 2 other cursor influences.  One is XCursor, and the other is the "com.canonical.Unity.Interface cursor-scale-factor" found with gsettings (in dconf-editor, the periods equate to level separators, like the "/" does in folder and file structures (Windows and DOS use "\" instead).

Para 15:__ The scale factor roughly corresponds to 0.75 is 18 pixels, 1.0 equals 24 pixels, 1.35 is 32, 2.0 is 48, and 2.70 is 64, at the screen resolutions I am most familiar with.

Para 16:__ Were the scale factor was truly used as intended. I believe the cursor would keep the same relative same size as the screen resolution changes.  That is not happening though, as changing the screen resolution also changes the size of the cursor displayed.

Para 17:__ If you go to a low resolution setting, the present method is probably best.  If you intend to use high resolution, the scale factor approach would probably be best.  But this is not a matter of choice for the user.

Para 18:__ It requires a logout/login sequence to change the mouse theme and size, so there is no practical way to adjust the cursor size on the fly.  I find white cursors best, but if you want black instead, you will also find custom DMZ-Black-Large and DMZ-Black-Medium files on this forum.  If you want more variety in mouse/cursor/X11 choices, they can be found via Google or Bing.  Just add linux, Ubuntu, or gnome to the search line to get ones that you can use.

Para 19:__ Picking the right theme means using update-alternatives, gsettings, or the gnome-tweak-tool and unity-tweak-tool.  Specific instructions are posted elsewhere.

Para 20:__ Some other interesting tools and options are "dpkg -l *" and "man -k [terms]".  The first lists all the packages in the Repositories, and the second lists information identified to man as possibly related to your area of interest.  Again, this is only the tip of the iceburg when it comes to what is possible with the commands and utilities provided in bash.

Para 21:__ The best way to learn how to use individual commands and utilities is to search for examples online in forums, webpages, and articles.  look for matches that have the key terms linux, unix, bash, ubuntu, and words to reflect what you want to do or which command or utility you want to learn in detail.  Don't hesitate to add terms like sample or example or tutorial in your search.

Para 22:__ You have five sources on your PC already:  man [command], info [command], help [command], and [command] --help are there to werve you, but rarely with real examples.  But your PC is cluttered with thousands of script files that illustrate the use of all the capabilities provided - you just have a problem weeding through the forest around you.  That is why the on-line search engines are so valuable, as it gets it all down to a few lines of code.

Para 23:__ Which is the common complaint concerning my own posts.  I cover so much real estate in one post that people get lost in the forest of my words.  But now I am paragraphing the words into smaller batches.  And numbering them too.  I hope this helps in some way.

Para 24:__ Shell programming is the fastest, cleanest, and most profound way for most people to program today.  You can compose code in hours that took the developers months or years to build up to the level we've arrived at.  I no longer write compiler code, except in extreme cases.   And the growth in what is possible has accelerated remarkably in recent years.  What you can't do with known utilities is often possible with tools like python or perl, and other areas of specialization.

Para 25:__ What non-programmers and most programmers have failed to grasp, is that we make reuse of existing code rather than focus on writing our own versions now.  It's like moving from cutting down trees and clearing the ground to build a log cabin, to now just erecting a modular home on ground that has been stripped of its trees.

Para 26:__ One approach takes time and effort and special skills.  The other just requires finding the right modular home and putting it up.  The do-it-yourself method takes  time, lots of it.  The modular assembly moght come pre-assembled and be put on the foundation by crane.  The difference in coding and reusing code is more dramatic than you can imagine.

Para 27:__ But to make full use of this capability, you need to move to the terminal and the command line mode.  You can never do it via a GUI interface, as that is really just for looks and to simplify some tasks while masking over options and capabilities.  Not to knock GUI entirely.  The UbuntuGNOME interface is terrific at what it does.

Para 28:__ Eyestrain.  Looking at a white screen is not like looking at a white sheet of paper.  The screen produces light, and the paper just reflects it.  All that white light is bad for your eyes, and people are suffering severe eye damage as a result.  If you can make the background dark and the text white instead, your eyes will thank you for it.   I like a dark red, dark blue, dark green, or dark purple myself.  And a solid color is less stressful than an image, as the image makes it harder to pick out the text.

Para 29:__ Web pages are particularly bad at showing white backgrounds.  I'm looking at one myself as I type this.  But I can fix that quick.  Slimjet gives you the option to complement the colors on on individual websites or pages, and that makes almost all whites black, and almost all blacks white.  White on black is not pretty, but a whole lot easier on the eyes.  Other colors look odd when they are bit-flipped like that.  Maybe someday someone will find a better method of keeping the white from dominating the screen as it does now.

Comment: Love this answer!  It's like a ChatGPT premonition.  In 2016!  ROFL

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

but be warned my screen went dead but was OK after a reboot. I also have logged in with the `Wayland` option. Got this from [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI).

Although it started to make the windowing system unstable :-/