# How to change display resolution and scaling using the command line

Tags: scripts, display-resolution, scaling, hdpi

I have a laptop with a hidpi display, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a resolution of 3840x2160 and 200% scale. Everything software I use looks fine with the exception of one so I would like to write a script so I can automatically change, let's say scaling to 100% and resolution to 1024x768.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: **To reviewers**: This duplicate doesn’t address the *scaling* in any way.

Comment: Suggest you visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/771673/ubuntu-gnome-and-high-resolution-screen-icons-in-qt-apps-are-too-small-how-to/826405#826405

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>This is an X Server solution and may not work with Wayland.</sup>

You can use `randr` for that, just determine the output name and available modes with `xrandr` and use the `--mode` and `--scale` options to change the settings. Provided this mode already exists, this would change the output DP2 to 3840x2160 with 200% scaling:

```
xrandr --output DP2 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 2x2
```

This changes to 1024x768 with 100% scaling:

```
xrandr --output DP2 --mode 1024x768 --scale 1x1
```

Further reading:

- [`man xrandr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xrandr.1.html)
- [How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/398740/507051)

---

To automate this I’d use `xdotool`, e.g. to call `xrandr` as soon an `xterm` window gets focus:

```
xdotool search --class xterm behave %@ focus exec xrandr
```